# How to get an Autoencoder to work when loading images using "tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory"?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I've been trying to modify the Tensorflow tutorial "Intro to Autoencoders" [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder) using my own custom database of images but I keep running into errors. If I simply copy the tutorial code using the MNIST database it works fine. I think it has something to do with loading my images using `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`.

Here is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

# Load and preprocess your custom image dataset
data_dir = ("C:/Users/anthony/Machine Learning/Images/Anomaly")

batch_size = 8
img_height = 256
img_width = 256
image_size = (img_height, img_width)

# Load and preprocess your data.
# "class_names" dictated by folder name and can be "None" below.
train_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    label_mode="int",
    labels="inferred",
    #class_names=["cat"]
    class_names=None
    )

val_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    label_mode="int",
    labels="inferred",
    #class_names=["cat"]
    class_names=None
    )

# Get the class names
class_names = train_dataset.class_names
print(f"*** class names {class_names} ***")
class_names_val = val_dataset.class_names
print(f"*** val class names {class_names_val} ***")

# Visualize training images before normalizing
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_dataset.take(1):
  for i in range(6):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")

# Define your model
# Get the number of classes
num_classes = len(class_names)
print(f"*** Number of classes {num_classes} ***")

norm_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
                    lambda x,
                    y: (norm_layer(x), y))

val_dataset = val_dataset.map(
                    lambda x,
                    y: (norm_layer(x), y))

image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(train_dataset))
first_image = image_batch[0]
# Notice the pixel values are now in `[0,1]`.
print(f"*** Min pixel {np.min(first_image)} Max pixel {np.max(first_image)} ***")

# Visualize training images after normalizing. Should be black images.
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_dataset.take(1):
  for i in range(6):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")

# Define the "image_batch" and "labels_batch"
for image_batch, labels_batch in train_dataset:
  print(f"*** image_batch shape {image_batch.shape} ***")
  print(f"*** label_batch shape {labels_batch.shape} ***")
  break

# Cannot use ".shape" since the "MapDataset" has no attribute "shape"
print(f"*** train_dataset shape image after loading {train_dataset} ***")
print(f"*** val_dataset shape image after loading {val_dataset} ***")

input_shape = image_size + (3,) # The shape of the input images
print(f"*** input_shape {input_shape} ***")

## First example: Basic autoencoder
#Define an autoencoder with two Dense layers: an `encoder`, which compresses the images into a 64 dimensional latent vector, and a `decoder`, that reconstructs the original image from the latent space.
#To define your model, use the [Keras Model Subclassing API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models).

class Autoencoder(Model):
  def __init__(self, latent_dim, shape):
    super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim
    self.shape = shape
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Flatten(),
      layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu'),
    ])
    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Dense(tf.math.reduce_prod(shape), activation='sigmoid'),
      layers.Reshape(shape)
    ])

  def call(self, x):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    return decoded

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_dataset = train_dataset.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_dataset = val_dataset.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

# slice array from "1" (inclusive) to 3 (not-inclusive). Shape is pixel dims.
shape = image_batch.shape[1:3]
print(f"*** shape {shape} ***")
latent_dim = 4 # was 64
autoencoder = Autoencoder(latent_dim, shape)

autoencoder.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=losses.MeanSquaredError())

# Train model but use "train_data" once because it's a dataset?
autoencoder.fit(train_dataset,
                epochs=1,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=val_dataset)

#Now that the model is trained, let's test it by encoding and decoding images from the test set.

encoded_imgs = autoencoder.encoder(x_test).numpy()
decoded_imgs = autoencoder.decoder(encoded_imgs).numpy()

n = 10
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
for i in range(n):
  # display original
  ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1)
  plt.imshow(x_test[i])
  plt.title("original")
  plt.gray()
  ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
  ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

  # display reconstruction
  ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1 + n)
  plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i])
  plt.title("reconstructed")
  plt.gray()
  ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
  ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Here is the output and error I get.

```
Found 20 files belonging to 1 classes.
Using 16 files for training.
Found 20 files belonging to 1 classes.
Using 4 files for validation.
*** class names ['cat'] ***
*** val class names ['cat'] ***
*** Number of classes 1 ***
*** Min pixel 0.0 Max pixel 1.0 ***
*** image_batch shape (8, 256, 256, 3) ***
*** label_batch shape (8,) ***
*** train_dataset shape image after loading <MapDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))> ***
*** val_dataset shape image after loading <MapDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))> ***
*** input_shape (256, 256, 3) ***
*** shape (256, 256) ***
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\anthony\Machine Learning\Coding examples\image_anomaly_training_5.py", line 166, in <module>
    autoencoder.fit(train_dataset,

  File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 24, in <module>
      start.main()
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 332, in main
      kernel.start()
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 712, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 215, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 601, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1905, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 510, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 499, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 406, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 730, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 390, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 528, in run_cell
      return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2914, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2960, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3185, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3377, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3457, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_24336\733835632.py", line 1, in <module>
      runfile('C:/Users/anthony/Machine Learning/Coding examples/image_anomaly_training_5.py', wdir='C:/Users/anthony/Machine Learning/Coding examples')
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 585, in runfile
      exec_code(file_code, filename, ns_globals, ns_locals,
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 465, in exec_code
      exec(compiled, ns_globals, ns_locals)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Machine Learning\Coding examples\image_anomaly_training_5.py", line 166, in <module>
      autoencoder.fit(train_dataset,
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1564, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 994, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1052, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 152, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 272, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 1486, in mean_squared_error
      return backend.mean(tf.math.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true), axis=-1)
Node: 'mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference'
required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5138]


2023-10-03 10:36:38.408240: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1768] INVALID_ARGUMENT: required broadcastable shapes
```

I've also tried adding this to the "autoencoder" `layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(shape)),` but then I get this error.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 256, 256) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 256, 256, 3).
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\anthony\Machine Learning\Coding examples\image_anomaly_training_5.py", line 167, in <module>
    autoencoder.fit(train_dataset,

  File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "C:\Users\ANTHON~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file6828qjlm.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)

  File "C:\Users\ANTHON~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filewp5n7958.py", line 10, in tf__call
    encoded = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).encoder, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 993, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Users\ANTHON~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filewp5n7958.py", line 10, in tf__call
        encoded = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).encoder, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "autoencoder_5" "                 f"(type Autoencoder).
    
    in user code:
    
        File "C:\Users\anthony\Machine Learning\Coding examples\image_anomaly_training_5.py", line 147, in call  *
            encoded = self.encoder(x)
        File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler  **
            raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
        File "C:\Users\anthony\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 277, in assert_input_compatibility
            raise ValueError(
    
        ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_12" "                 f"(type Sequential).
        
        Input 0 of layer "dense_13" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 65536, but received input with shape (None, 196608)
        
        Call arguments received by layer "sequential_12" "                 f"(type Sequential):
          • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)
          • training=True
          • mask=None
    
    
    Call arguments received by layer "autoencoder_5" "                 f"(type Autoencoder):
      • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)
```